# How to access the multiple return variables compiled in python

Tags: python, c++, segmentation-fault, ctypes, stdtuple

I am new to programming, I defined a function in c++ with tuple method for two returned variables, after I compiled the files, In the python file, I try to access the two returned variables inside the dynamic library which have been compiled, but it is not working, there is segmentation error happened when I tried to run the python program. But I actually success with single return variable from c++, I think there is might be special trick for accessing the two returned variable with tuple method from python.

The following is the c++ code with two returned variables with tuple method

```
std::tuple<double, double> Cassie2d::Step(ControllerTorque* action)
{
  dyn_model_.setState(mj_data_->qpos, mj_data_->qvel);
  dyn_state_.UpdateDynamicState(&dyn_model_);

  mju_copy(mj_data_->ctrl, action->torques, nU);
  mj_step(mj_model_, mj_data_);
  return std::make_tuple(mj_data_->qacc,mj_data_->time);
  Render();
}
```

The following is the python method I was applied, due to both of the returned variables are double type.

```
lib.StepTorque.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.POINTER(ControllerTorque)]
lib.StepTorque.restype = ctypes.c_double
```

I guess the `restype` is not just equal to `ctypes.c_double`, because it worked for one returned variable and it might not work for two returned variables.

Really appreciate for the help!

Comment: Provide some details - what python library do you use? Segmentation error suggest that you may initialize python, but not some of additional modules (numpy perhaps?). Multile return can usually be accesed like: `VarA, VarB = function_name(arguments)`

Comment: lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('../../bin/libcassie2d.so'). The c++ file compiled into a dynamic library which is libcassie2d.so, the code above is loading the library in python, I could load the one return variable, not two variables which I defined in the c++

Comment: `ctypes` is for **C**, not C++. It doesn't understand C++ classes and needs standard C types like `double`, not `std::tuple<double, double>`.

Answer (score 0):

With `return std::make_tuple(mj_data_->qacc,mj_data_->time)` your creating a structure which holds two variables, defined in parenthesis. If the function would be call from native C++ code you should be able to unpack it using std:tie, eq:

```
double a, b;
std::tie(a,b) = Step(arg);
```

However you need to call it directly from python, which has totally different syntax for returning multiple variables (C++ pair or tuple is kind of bypass missing functionality). I see two option in python.

1. Give your C++ function a two callbacks to python, and send variables separately this way:

   ```
   void Cassie2d::Step(ControllerTorque* action, callback1, callback2)
   {
   dyn_model_.setState(mj_data_->qpos, mj_data_->qvel);
   dyn_state_.UpdateDynamicState(&dyn_model_);

   mju_copy(mj_data_->ctrl, action->torques, nU);
   mj_step(mj_model_, mj_data_);
   callback1(mj_data_->qacc);
   callback2(mj_data_->time);
   Render();
   }
   ```
2. (Recommened) You can try to use native python option to serve multiple return. Left you C++ function in its initial form and call in python this way:

   ```
   VarA, VarB = Step(action)
   ```

   I assume you have a reference to `Cassie2d::Step(ControllerTorque* action)` method in your python code, however you provided very small snippet.

Comment: lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('../../bin/libcassie2d.so')
c_double_p = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double) Those two lines of code was used to access the dynamic library which have been compiled from c++ code, also, lib.StepTorque.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.POINTER(ControllerTorque)]
lib.StepTorque.restype = None are for defining the input argument and return types using ctypes, could you please tell me what to do with the restype please, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I'm not sure how your code works. So the line `lib.StepTorque.restype = ctypes.c_double` extract value? If yes, what part of this code refer to the name od variable in which the returned value is storage?